# Adding a row based upon conditionals -- trying to do it the most R way

Tags: r

I have a data set that records the averages of air pollution coming from different kinds of monitors by county and year. If the monitor is known to only be Monitor 1 it is coded as such, otherwise the average is coded as "all". If there isn't anything other than Monitor 1 though, so far there isn't an All. I want to take the values of Monitor 1 and create a new row with the exact same information labeled as All, but only if All doesn't already exist. Example:

```
Year     County     Type         Average
2001     Adams      Monitor 1    8.9
2001     Benton     Monitor 1    6.5
2001     Benton     All          7.1
```

In this case, I would want it to become:

```
Year     County     Type         Average
2001     Adams      Monitor 1    8.9
2001     Adams      All          8.9 ***identical to the above
2001     Benton     Monitor 1    6.5
2001     Benton     All          7.1
```

I can think of a few kludgy, convoluted starts to doing this, or I could try to mess with conditionals. But I am trying to improve my R ability and keep my coding consistent with how R works best (there's a phrase for this I'm forgetting...!) Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Seems a bit strange. Shouldn't there be rows with things like "Monitor 2"? How many different kinds of monitors are there?

Comment: I tried not to provide too much random detail but if it helps: there's really only two broad categories of monitors -  monitor 1 (one kind of federal monitor) and all others (our state's monitors of assorted types PLUS the federal monitors). We run a portal where we let people query, and one of the filters is if they want only federal monitors or if they want everything. We don't have the option to just use state monitors. All of the detail about individual monitors is lost during a bunch of split-apply-combine steps earlier in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, I would use the `ave` function to determine if each row is of Type "Monitor 1" and is the only row for a particular county:

```
(to.duplicate <- ave(as.character(dat$Type), dat$County, FUN=function(x) if(identical(x, "Monitor 1")) { TRUE } else {rep(FALSE, length(x))}) == "TRUE")
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Then I would generate all the new rows in one shot and use `rbind` to add it to the data frame:

```
new.dat <- dat[to.duplicate,]
new.dat$Type <- "All"
rbind(dat, new.dat)
#   Year County      Type Average
# 1 2001  Adams Monitor 1     8.9
# 2 2001 Benton Monitor 1     6.5
# 3 2001 Benton       All     7.1
# 4 2001  Adams       All     8.9
```